# Shiny UI not reading dashboard format

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a UI file that looks as such:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Sales and Leads"),


  #sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Breakdown by Day", tabName = "overview", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Breakdown by Month", tabName = "borders", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Breakdown by Year", tabName = "sectors", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),

  #body content
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              .content-wrapper, .main-body {
                              font-weight: normal;
                              font-size: 18px;
                              } '))),

    tabItems(

      #first tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "overview",

              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsYesterday"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesYesterday"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsYesterday")
              )
      ),

      #second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "borders",
              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsMonth"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesMonth"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsMonth"))
      ),

      #third tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "sectors",
              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsYear"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesYear"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsYear"),
                fluidRow(
                  infoBoxOutput("DialsAll"),
                  infoBoxOutput("SalesAll"),
                  infoBoxOutput("LeadsAll"))
              )
      )
    )
    )
    )
```

When I run the code though, all that appears is the very first input box ("DialsYesterday").

All the other inputs I have don't appear. When you click on the other tabs, it's just a blank. I must be doing something wrong, but not sure what. I don't get any error messages, so it's not a server side issue. I just think I have the order operations wrong with how it's built.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried based on your UI code as you have not provided enough code to reproduce the same. Here is my code and its working perfectly. you can change according to your requirement.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Sales and Leads"),


  #sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Breakdown by Day", tabName = "overview", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Breakdown by Month", tabName = "borders", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Breakdown by Year", tabName = "sectors", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),

  #body content
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                              .content-wrapper, .main-body {
                              font-weight: normal;
                              font-size: 18px;
                              } '))),

    tabItems(

      #first tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "overview",

              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsYesterday"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesYesterday"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsYesterday")
              )
      ),

      #second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "borders",
              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsMonth"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesMonth"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsMonth"))
      ),

      #third tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "sectors",
              fluidRow(
                infoBoxOutput("DialsYear"),
                infoBoxOutput("SalesYear"),
                infoBoxOutput("LeadsYear")
              ),
                fluidRow(
                  infoBoxOutput("DialsAll"),
                  infoBoxOutput("SalesAll"),
                  infoBoxOutput("LeadsAll")
              )

      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$DialsYesterday<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(" TAB 1 Title 1 DialsYesterday", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 1")
  })

  output$SalesYesterday<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 1 Title 2 SalesYesterday", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 2")
  })

  output$LeadsYesterday<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 1 Title 3 LeadsYesterday", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })



  output$DialsMonth<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 2 Title 1 DialsMonth", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 1")
  })

  output$SalesMonth<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 2 Title 2 SalesMonth", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 2")
  })

  output$LeadsMonth<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 2 Title 3 LeadsMonth", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })


  output$DialsYear<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 1 DialsYear", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 1")
  })

  output$SalesYear<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 2 SalesYear", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 2")
  })

  output$LeadsYear<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 3 LeadsYear", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })

  output$DialsAll<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 3 DialsAll", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })

  output$LeadsAll<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 3 LeadsAll", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })

  output$SalesAll<-renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("TAB 3 Title 3 SalesAll", value = 100,subtitle = "subtitile 3")
  })




}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)][1]][1]
```